# Having trouble with y axis percentage range

Tags: percentage, yaxis

I have a dataset from FitBit users over 30 days. I have aggregated this data to look at monthly total activity based on hours at each intensity level. My chart is a stacked column chart with the user id's on the x axis, and the hours for the y axis.

the range is from 0-700 hours and there are 4 categories sedentary hours, lightly active hours, fairly active hours and very active hours that create the total. I added these 4 columns to the measure values, but when I try to change the y axis to a percentage it multiplies the value and gives 70000%.

I have tried changing from sum to average, tried to make all percentage of total but that gives me null. I imagine the answer is simple but I cannot figure it out. I'd really appreciate some help. I'll attach screenshots.[shot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cyoz.png)[shot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkKjv.png)

I tried to calculate a field with the sum of all columns, then divide by the each column but it didn't work for me.